# Maximum order of an element in Alternating group of degree 10.

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations, symmetric-groups

> What is the maximum order of any element in $A_{10}$?

My attempt: I tried this problem. But I am not sure about the answer. My answer is 21 because 10 can be written as 7+3. $A_{10}$ can have two disjoint cycle of length 7 and 3. Lcm of 7 and 3 is 21 which is the maximum order of an element of $A_{10}$. Is it correct? If not please guide me.

Comment: There is one more case $2+3+5 = 10$, but obviously this is corresponds to odd permutation, therefore you are correct the answer is $21$.

Comment: Ha. This was problem 9 on an assignment I gave earlier this year. Here are my solutions (but on this problem, I don't give a detailed answer). https://rutherglen.science.mq.edu.au/math337s115/sols/A3_sols.pdf

Comment: Thanks.I have one more doubt.how many odd permutation of order 4 does $S_6$ have?

Comment: I got the answer and it is 90.