# Finding maximum order of element of $A_{12}$ without brute force

Tags: group-theory, permutations, finite-groups

I would like to solve this question. I think the answer is 35, but I do not know how to do it without extremely long analysis of possibilities.

Is there a short way to solve this problem? Maybe the fact that $A_{12}$ is simple helps?

Comment: I don't think it's $30$.

Comment: Do you know an element with order greater than 30?

Comment: Do you know how to find the maximum order of an element in $S_{12}$?

Comment: There's room for a 7-cycle and a 5-cycle disjoint from it.

Comment: Not quite without brute force.

Comment: And see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1600495/11619).

Comment: There is some brute force, sure. But you can save a lot of work if you just think a little about how lengths of cycles affect the order.

Comment: I know that the order is the lcm of lengths of cycles. But, still there seems to be a lot of brute force to find the maximum. For example, I know that finding the maximum order of element of $S_n$ is hard problem, that is why we rely on Landau's approximation for this.

Comment: For general $n$, sure, it's a tough problem. For $n=12$ specifically, not really.

Comment: With the new updated answer 35, I think I will give it another try to prove. I had misconception that the sum of lengths must be odd for the permutation is even. Now I see this is not necessarily the case. I will inform you if I have found an elegant proof

Comment: Same question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1346815/maximum-order-of-an-element-in-alternating-group-of-degree-10).

Comment: I know that I have to look at prime powers to find the answer. But, that also seems to be a brute-force problem. I was wondering if this case is special, like if $A_{12}$ is isomorphic to a group where it is easier to answer this question.